# Rectangle with round corners with gradient fills and text

Tags: tikz-pgf

Struggling to draw following image. Any help will be highly appreciable. Following is my code

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows,shadows,patterns,calc}

% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    myrectangle/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum width=160, minimum 
 height=40, ultra thick, rounded corners=10, green}
    ]   
    \node[myrectangle] (a) at (0,0) {Energy Efficiency Applications};
    \node[myrectangle, right=0 of a] (b) {Less use of buffers and registers 
 instruction set optimization};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    myrectangle/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum width=160, minimum 
height=40, ultra thick, rounded corners=10, blue}
    ]   
    \node[myrectangle] (a) at (0,0) {Power Aware Resource Management};
    \node[myrectangle, right=0 of a] (b) {Energy aware task scheduling and 
resource provisioning policies};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what you try so far? where you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that these kind of diagramas are easily drawn with `tcbraster` or `tcbitemize` (from `tcolorbox`). Boxes width is automatically computed (\texwidth divided by number of columns) and equal height for all boxes in a row is obtained with `raster equal height=rows` and two compilations. And also the code is simpler.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\tcbset{
    mybox/.style={
        enhanced,
        notitle,
        colframe=#1!80!black,
        interior style={top color=#1!5, bottom color=#1!30},
        fontupper=\bfseries,
        halign=flush center,
        valign=center
    },
    myraster/.style={
        raster equal height=rows,
        raster row skip=0pt,
        raster column skip=0pt,
        raster row 1/.style={mybox=green},
        raster row 2/.style={mybox=cyan},
        raster row 3/.style={mybox=red}
    }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcbitemize}[myraster]
\tcbitem Energy Efficiency Applications
\tcbitem Less use of buffers and registers, instruction set optimization, etc.
\tcbitem Power Aware Resource Management
\tcbitem Energy aware task scheduling and resource provisioning policies
\tcbitem Hardware Energy Efficiency
\tcbitem Clock frequency, voltage supply, logical gates, transistors, etc.
\end{tcbitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

- Set size of the nodes with `minimum width` and `minimum height`.
- Give color as argument to new defined style `mynode`.
- Use `top color` and `bottom color` for color gradient.
- Use `align=center, text width=35mm` to allow automatic linebreak and get centered text.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
            node distance=0pt,
            mynode/.style={
                ultra thick, rectangle, rounded corners=5, draw=#1,
                minimum width=40mm, minimum height=14mm,
                align=center, text width=35mm, text=black,
                top color=white, bottom color=#1!40!white
            }
        ]

            \node[mynode=green] (a) at (0,0) {\textbf{A asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf}};
            \node[mynode=green, right=of a] (b) {B};

            \node[mynode=blue, below=of a] (c) {C};
            \node[mynode=blue, right=of c] (d) {D};

            \node[mynode=red, below=of c] (e) {E};
            \node[mynode=red, right=of e] (f) {F};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]